# using overloaded function of the base class

Tags: c++, overloading, derived-class

I try to do something like

```
class base {
public:
    virtual double operator() (double val) = 0;
    virtual double operator() (double prev, double val) {
        return prev + operator()(val);
    }
};

class derived: public base {
    virtual double operator() (double val) {
        return someting_clever;
    }
};
```

I want to overload the operator() to use it with different algorithms such as std::accumulate or std::transform. I'm totally happy with the base class definition of operator()(double, double). However I can't call it from the derived class. Do I have to rewrite the same code for each class I derive from base?

Comment: I think you are experiencing the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746391/deriving-from-a-class-with-operator-overloading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that defining a function in a derived class hides the same function in the base class; this is the reason why you cannot access `operator()(double, double)` from the derived class.

But there is a way to do it: you can just use a `using` directive in your derived class:

```
class derived: public base {
    using base::operator();
    virtual double operator() (double val) {
        return someting_clever;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a using directive?

```
class derived: public base {
    virtual double operator() (double val) {
        return someting_clever;
    }
    using base::operator();
};
```